# Czech specific characters are not correctly encoded

Tags: javascript, html, character-encoding

I am fighting with problem of encoding Czech letters from source generates by Java Script and its rendering on final page.

source code in JS:

```
if(obj.hits.total===0) { $('#results-list').append( '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">No result: Look before you leap.Dvakrát měř, jednou řež. :)</div>' ); }
```

I am using html meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and also `<script>` attribute

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
```

The index.jsp is encoded by UTF-8.

The result is

> No result: Look before you leap.DvakrÃ¡t mÄ›Å™, jednou Å™eÅ¾. :)

Expected result is

> No result: Look before you leap.Dvakrát měř, jednou řež. :)

Don't know what and where else I have to say to HTML that let it is necoded properly.

Any idea what I overlooked?

Comment: You are already specifying the character set but it  is displaying it as WINDOWS-1251. are you using a web-server that is running on a windows host and it would be helpful if you can post your response headers too.